# Sybase - SAP ASE - replication server: routing declaration

Tags: replication, sybase

I'm trying to declare a routing in SAP Replication Server.

I have:

- A server (let's call it S1) with ASE and RS server (let's call it RS1).
- A server (let's call it S2) with ASE and RS server (let's call it RS2).
- A server (let's call it S3) with ASE server.
- I have A replication in RS1 from database in S1 to databases in S1 and S2.

Now I'm trying to add a replication to a database in S3 via RS2: a routing from RS1 to RS2 and a subscription to the DB in S3.

I declared the routing, an agent between the 2 RSSDs.

When I'm trying to set the subscription (in RS2) to the database in S3 I've got an error - saying that it doesn't know the replication definition.

Anyone familiar with routing declaration?

Thanks.

Comment: you'd better ask this at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: No its a normal SAP replication server question not a server issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I resolve it.

Especially what I did was arrange the settings and delete duplicates. Then I set up the connections again, and then the subscription.

- drop connections.
- Drop route.
- Purge route - clean up any old references that were created with the failed create route.
- suspend connection.
- Stop rep agent and ran the rs_zeroltm to tell the rep agent to start at the end of the log and restarted the rep agent.
- resume connection
- re-created the route between the RSSDs.
- verify the replication definitions were copied to the target RSSD
- create a subscription
- resume the replicate connection on the second RS

Answer (score 0):

The critical thing with routes is they both need to be in the same replication system, meaning they must share the SAME primary rep server (known as the ID server) - this contains information about all the replication servers in the replication server setup, or domain as it's known. You can create many replication servers in a domain, but for them to be able to link together via routes they must all use the same ID server.

NOTE: You can't set them up separately and then link them later. When you set up RS2 you have say RS1 is the id server and put in all the required info into rs_init for RS1 as you run through the various rs_init menus to create RS2.

If that's been done already correctly then:

Firstly set up route between RS1 and RS2 (via a 'create route' command [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32410.1520/html/refman/X22364.htm)) if you want data to flow in both directions at some point it makes sense to setup routes both ways between RS1 and RS2, as by definition a route is in one direction. This will mean you can set replication up between any of the three ASE instances.

NOTE: You need to check that the route is actually fully up and active (via admin who) - if not then you need to start looking through the rep server errorlogs as to why that's failing e.g. missing entry in interfaces file, login issue etc.

One routes are set-up you can create a subscription replication definition against the source database and a subscription at the target database when these are attached to different replication servers. This can be at the table-level or a database-level replication definition (MSA) depending on what your aim is.

Comment: I assume by `primary rep server` you meant `id server` ? otherwise `RS2 (a **repserver**) ... set it up with the same primary **repserver** as RS1 (a **repserver**)` doesn't make sense

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I installed each of the servers as RS on its own, and only afterwards I created the route and try to "connect" them.

Should I re-install the second RS server (RS2)? or I can edit a property there and it will set RS1 as primary rep server?

Comment: @markp - yes sorry the ID server I was clearly half asleep when replying corrected main answer:)

Comment: @itaigitt - no unfortunately you will have to re-install RS2 you can't link them later. When you run the rs_init command for RS2 when you re-create it you need to specify RS1 as the ID server in the setup process and add the relevant information relating to RS1 and then you can do the create route once it's been recreated/